# Update an Object in an array which is inside an Object

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Newbie Help!
I want help in updating a value in an Object which is inside an array contained in an Object again!

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a641fc1b66d0a1b7c274c99"),
  "comments" : [ { "author" : { "id" : ObjectId("5a5c93954c5b6f35953d38e0"), 
                  "username" : "Anton" },
                  "_id" : ObjectId("5a641fceb66d0a1b7c274c9a"),
                  "text" : "I love this place!", "__v" : 0 },

                { "author" : { "id" : ObjectId("5a5c93954c5b6f35953d38e0"), 
                  "username" : "Anton" }, 
                  "_id" : ObjectId("5a642023b66d0a1b7c274c9b"),
                  "text" : "Supercool!", "__v" : 0 } ],

  "campGroundName" : "Desert Creek",
  "campGroundImage":
                "https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7205/7121863467_eb0aa64193.jpg",
  "description" : "  Donec rhoncus, enim vel semper pharetra, dui justo accumsan neque, nec dictum tortor nibh id es", "__v" : 2,
  "addedBy" : { "id" : ObjectId("5a5c93954c5b6f35953d38e0"), "username" : "Anton" } }`
```

Here I want to access the value of text in the comments array of the object..

How can I update the value of text in Mongoose??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you want to update all the comments, or any particular comment?

Comment: A particular comment alone using it's ObjectId

Comment: Get inside your parent object, and then search for particular comment with it;s comment id, or directly provide comment id search for it, use `findOneAndUpdate`. :)

Comment: I tried everything that I could do with all my power but no progress..I couldn't do this :(

Comment: Try `.update({"_id" : ObjectId("5a641fc1b66d0a1b7c274c99"), "comments._id": ObjectId("5a641fceb66d0a1b7c274c9a")}, {$set:{"comments.$.text":"some new text"}});`

Comment: I'm getting a cast error now :( ... It's really frustrating...

Comment: Anything I can help you with ? Add the schema and include the error in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Use $elemMatch for the find query to search inside a nested array, then use "myarrayfield.$.keyoftheobjectinarray" for the update :

Sample to update all u key with 10 in an array of nested object matching u == 1

```
db.a.update({"a": {$elemMatch:{"u": 1}}},{$set:{"a.$.u": 10}},{multi: true, upsert:false})
```